# Delegate methods are not firing in multithreading program in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

Hi am new to multithreading.... below is the code i wrote to download a video in separate thread but delegates methods not firing up anybody please help me to solve this... thanks in advance..

```
- (void)downLoad {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{ 
_videoData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://km.support.apple.com/library/APPLE/APPLECARE_ALLGEOS/HT1211/sample_iTunes.mov"]] delegate:self];
        //saving is done on main thread
});
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
    _length = [response expectedContentLength];
    NSLog(@"Size:%0.2f",_length);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    [_videoData appendData:data];
    float progress = (float)[_videoData length]/(float)_length;
    NSLog(@"Progress:%0.2f",progress);
   _timeLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2F%%",progress*100];
   [_progressView setProgress:progress animated:YES];
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError");
}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self saveLocally:_videoData];
        NSLog(@"File Saved !");
    });   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NSURLConnection enqueues delegate calls in a run loop (NSRunLoop), which is fine if you create a NSURLConnection from a thread that has one (like the main thread).

But you are using grand central dispatch (GCD) which creates threads and destroys / deactivates them as it likes. I don't really see the need to move download logic to a separate thread, as only the callbacks will be invoked on your main thread (which is pretty useful if you want to do UI work) but NSURlConnection will do its download magic on a background thread.

If you want to do download data processing in the background while downloading, you might want to look into NSURLSession (iOS 7) as it supports GCD queues.